# My app went to beta review, I haven't applied for it

Tags: ios, app-store

I submitted my app update on Saturday morning in Apple appstore, after a couple of hours I got message that your app is in review.It went on till now friday 25, still in review after 6 days.I checked the activity and I found that the app is in beta review.I have not opted for it..how to get out of this? and get the review done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact App Store Review team. There's a "contact" link at the bottom of the page, when logged in to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Yea I agree. "Beta Review" isn't actually a thing anymore on the new test flight - there's only one review process. Best to contact them and make sure your review is on the up and up.

Comment: Exact same thing is happening to me. Contacted the review team but haven't heard back.